# Are global variables just properties on the `window` object?

Tags: javascript, browser, scope, window

Whenever I see a website on the browser an instance of javascript is running. And I can declare a global variable in the console (DevTools);

```
var a = 1234567890;
```

This variable has been declared in global scope such that I can get the value of the variable like so;

```
> a 
1234567890
```

However, I can also do this;

```
> window.a 
1234567890
```

Am I understanding it correctly that the `window` object is the object that contains all the global variables within the website instance on the browser? If so to what scope does the window object belong? This is confusing me a little bit;

```
> window 
Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external:, ...}  
> window.window 
Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external:, ...}  
> window.window.window 
Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external:, ...}
```

Is the `window` object the ultimate global object and does that have an object called `window` that refers back to itself?

Comment: We can see that window is pointing to itself.

Comment: That "duplicate" question is not a duplicate. This question: "Is a global variable just a property on Window?" That question: "How do I list all global variables?"

Comment: @SteveBennett, this question's title is "list of all global variables javascript". You can always edit the title if you like.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is the `window` object the ultimate global object and does that have an object called `window` that refers back to itself?

Yes, and yes. This, for instance, returns `true`:

```
window.window.window.window.window === window.window;
```

You can, if you are interested, get a list of all the properties of the `window` object (and hence all global variables) with `Object.keys`:

```
console.log(Object.keys(window));
```

Note, however, that if you are spending too much time thinking about global variables, there is probably a problem with the architecture of your code.

Comment: good answer. i was more conserned with the fundamental architecture about the web. i avoid globals whenever possible :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the `window` object is

## The Global Object<sub>[(§15.1 ES5 Specification)](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1)</sub>

> The unique global object is created before control enters any
>   execution context.
>
> Unless otherwise specified, the standard built-in properties of the
>   global object have attributes {[[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]:
>   false, [[Configurable]]: true}.
>
> The global object does not have a [[Construct]] internal property; it
>   is not possible to use the global object as a constructor with the new
>   operator.
>
> The global object does not have a [[Call]] internal property; it is
>   not possible to invoke the global object as a function.
>
> The values of the [[Prototype]] and [[Class]] internal properties of
>   the global object are implementation-dependent.
>
> In addition to the properties defined in this specification the global
>   object may have additional host defined properties. **This may include a
>   property whose value is the global object itself;** for example, in the
>   *HTML document object model the **window property of the global object is
>   the global object itself.***

Answer (score 1):

All global variables become properties of the window object.

```
>>> window.somevar = 1;
1
>>> somevar
1
```

And all of the **core JavaScript functions are methods** of the window object.

Comment: What does "core JavaScript functions" mean? Is `String.indexOf` a core Javascript function?

Comment: @lonesomeday No, this is method of objects,from core javascript functions i meant to say that the functions that are not the part of any object like parseFloat,parseInt,isNaN