# Why the global variable is added to the window's properties in javascript?

Tags: javascript

It is added to one of window's properties when you define global variable.

```
var foo = 'foo';

console.log(window.foo);
//result : 'foo'
```

As you know,  The scope of the JavaScript variable is function.

For global variables to be stored, I must use a function because of scope.

But it is not a global variable already if I wrap the variable by a function.

You can't help but add to window's properties in my opinion.

However, the guess is just a guess.

I've always wondered why it is happened.

But I don't still know why.

Is there anyone who know why?

Comment: *"As you know, The scope of the JavaScript variable is function"* this is something *you* are assuming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are global variables just properties on the \`window\` object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855823/are-global-variables-just-properties-on-the-window-object)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855823/are-global-variables-just-properties-on-the-window-object

Comment: *Because the spec says so, because that's the way Brendan wrote it…*

Comment: @liam if you think the duplicate answers your question, then yes. It's not mandatory but it would help