# howto retrieve asp.net appSettings key from front-end .js file using knockout.js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I have an asp.net backend application and i am using web.config and other files to store configuration keys.

I have a front-end built with javascript files using knockout.js.

We would like to know how can we retrieve key value from web.config in backend and read this value in front-end using javascript and knockout.js.

Is there a simple way to do this ???, Views are javascript files and not asp.net web pages

Comment: Why not inject it into your JS via a release pipeline process?

Comment: `web.config` is used by ASP.NET 4.x - please confirm if you're using `.aspx` (WebForms or MVC 2.x) or `.cshtml` (MVC 3.x+) for your pages/views.

Comment: Javascript cannot read the config file on the server, and for very good reason. You could do as David L says or create some kind of proxy endpoint that serves appropriate settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can render values directly to JavaScript `<script>` in your view/HTML/page files.

  - And then **any** JavaScript (with or without Knockout, jQuery, React, Redux, AngularJS, Angular2+, whatever) can access those values immediately.
- **IMPORTANT:** Be sure to correctly JS-encode (not HTML-encode!) C#/.NET `String` values when rendering them as JavaScript string literals! ...otherwise backslashes and quotes will be rendered literally which will break your rendered `<script>` element and likely introduce significant XSS vulnerabilities.

  - In ASP.NET 4.x, use `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` to ensure C#/.NET `string` values are correctly and safely encoded to JavaScript strings.
  - In ASP.NET Core you can continue to use `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` (in [the now almost empty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode?view=net-6.0) <del>`System.Web.dll`</del> `System.Web.HttpUtility.dll` in .NET Core 2.x or later) however *now* the preferred API in .NET is `System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder`'s `Encode` method (tip: use `JavaScriptEncoder.Default.Encode`).
  - Note that `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` can optionally add delimiting quotes for you, but `System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder` never renders outer quotes.

### For Razor `.cshtml` in ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET 4.x WebPages:

(I assume your `<head>` is in `_Layout.cshtml`)

```
@using System.Configuration
@using System.Web.Configuration

<html>
<head>
    <script>

var myAppSetting = '@( HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode( WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myAppSetting"], addDoubleQuotes: false ) )';

    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

### For ASP.NET WebForms `.aspx`/`.ascx`/`.master` and/or ASP.NET MVC 1.x and 2.x using the WebForms ASPX View Engine:

- (I assume your `<head>` is in `Layout.master`)
- Use `<%=` instead of `<%:` to render directly, btw, as we don't want to HTML-encode this JavaScript string literal.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Configuration" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Configuration" %>
<html>
<head>
    <script>

var myAppSetting = '<%= HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode( WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myAppSetting"], addDoubleQuotes: false ) %>';

    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

### For ASP.NET Core MVC's Razor `.cshtml` views:

- Use `@inject IConfiguration` to get immediate access to .NET Core's appSettings.
- You can use either `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(...)` or `System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.Default.Encode(...)` in ASP.NET Core (including .NET 6).

  - Don't forget outer-quotes!
- Use `Html.Raw()` to render the JS literal string. **Do not** use the normal Razor "write" syntax (i.e. `@( value )` or `@value`) because it will HTML-encode your JavaScript, which you don't want.
- Like so:

```
@using System.Text.Encodings.Web
@inject IConfiguration Config

<html>
<head>
    <script>

var myAppSetting = '@Html.Raw( JavaScriptEncoder.Default.Encode( this.Config.GetValue<String>("appSettings:myAppSetting") )';

    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Note that if you want `null` values from your appSettings.json to appear as JavaScript `null` literals then you need to do that manually - you can use a [`@functions` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-6.0#functions) to handle this, like so:

```
@using System.Text.Encodings.Web
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html
@inject IConfiguration Config
@functions{
    
    public HtmlString GetAppSettingJSString( String name )
    {
        if( name is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));

        String? appSettingValue = this.Config.GetValue<String?>( "appSettings:" + name );
        return ToJSStringLiteral( appSettingValue );
    }

    private static readonly HtmlString _nullLiteral = new HtmlString( "null" );

    public static HtmlString ToJSStringLiteral( String? value )
    {
        if( value is null ) return _nullLiteral;
        
        String jsStringLiteralChars = JavaScriptEncoder.Default.Encode( value );
        return new HtmlString( '"' + jsStringLiteralChars + '"' );
    }
}

<html>
<head>
    <script>
var myAppSetting = @Html.Raw( this.GetAppSettingJSString( "myAppSetting" ) );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

So now the `<script>` above will be rendered as either this:

```
<script>
var myAppSetting = "foobarbaz";
</script>
```

...or this:

```
<script>
var myAppSetting = null;
</script>
```

---

Any script (except ES Modules, I think?) can access `myAppSetting` via the implicit `global` (aka `window`) object, as all top-level `var` declarations [become global properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19855823/159145).

So like so:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    alert( "myAppSetting: \"" + window.myAppSetting + "\"" );

} );
</script>
```